# Need help understanding CSS selectivity rules

Tags: css

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
    #foo  { color: blue; }
    a.bar { color: red; }
    #foo .baz  { background-color: cyan; }
    a.bar > .baz { background-color: yellow; }
</style></head>
<body>
    <div id="foo">
        <a href="#" class="bar">
            <span class="baz">TEXT</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a CSS noob, but my intuition tells me that `a.bar` is a more specific match for the `<span>` containing `TEXT` than `#foo`, and that `TEXT` should appear in red with a yellow background. Or if `#foo` is more specific, then `TEXT` should be in blue with a cyan background.

Instead, `TEXT` appears (as tested on Chrome, IE8) in red with a cyan background. How is it that `a.bar` is more specific than `#foo`, but `#foo .baz` is more specific than `a.bar > .baz`? How would I get this text to appear with red and <strike>cyan</strike> yellow with the least disruption (smallest set of changes) to the styles I have already specified?

Comment: appear with red and cyan with the least disruption? Do you mean red background with cyan text instead?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the goal is red text with yellow background.

Comment: also note that it is "CSS Specificity", not "Selectivity", but that's what I google'ed for and came here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're seeing with the text color doesn't have to do with which selector is applied. Both selectors are being applied, but to different elements. Translated to inline styles your CSS would look like:

```
<body>
    <div id="foo" style="color: blue;">
        <a href="#" class="bar" style="color: red;">
            <span class="baz" style="background-color: cyan;">TEXT</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

`background-color: yellow;` was overridden by the more specific selector, but your other selectors don't override each other. They apply to different elements. The span will inherit the `color` from it's closest ancestor which has a specified value for `color`. In this case that is the `<a>`.

If you want a yellow background with minimal changes I would suggest making that selector have higher specificity by prepending `#foo` onto it like `#foo a.bar > .baz`. Here is a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/qDyBT/).

Answer (score 1):

This is all down to specificity. [Here is a good (old) resource](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) (checkout the jpg you can download)

Comment: Love that star wars specificity wars!

Comment: I still don't get it. So `#foo .baz` (specifity 110) beats `a.bar>.baz` (021), but then why does `a.bar` (011) beat `#foo` (100) ?

Comment: @mob, you need to consider first which elements a selector refers to. Specificity has no role there. The selector `#foo` matches only the element with `id=foo`, not any element inside it.

Comment: So it's not all down to specificity. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite messy; it's supposed to be intuitive, but once you dig deeper, things might not work quite as expected. Smashing Magazine has put together a comprehensive guide, though:
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/