# How to style a dart-polymer material-design application

Tags: css, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm trying to apply a theme to my dart-polymer material-design application, everywhere I look at videos and tutorials, it is suggested that with a few lines of CSS you can change the look of the whole application.

I've even generated a theme just now using: http://www.materialpalette.com/grey/red and it gave me the following CSS:

```
/* Palette generated by Material Palette - materialpalette.com/grey/red */
.dark-primary-color    { background: #616161; }
.default-primary-color { background: #9E9E9E; }
.light-primary-color   { background: #F5F5F5; }
.text-primary-color    { color: #212121; }
.accent-color          { background: #FF5252; }
.primary-text-color    { color: #212121; }
.secondary-text-color  { color: #727272; }
.divider-color         { border-color: #B6B6B6; }
```

... which I've included in my default stylesheet, but with no colour changes.

So if this is my custom polymer element:

```
<polymer-element name="main-app" class="default">
  <template>
    <style type="text/css">
      :host {
        display: block;
      }

    </style>

    <core-toolbar class="default">
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
        <span flex class="default">
          <paper-tabs selected="0">
            <paper-tab>ITEM ONE</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>ITEM TWO</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>ITEM THREE</paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
        </span>
        <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
    </core-toolbar>


</template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main-app.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

And this is my index.html using that custom main-app component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

  ...

  <link rel="import" href="packages/falm/main-app.html">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">


</head>
<body unresolved>
  <main-app class="default"></main-app>
  <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</body>
</html>
```

... what is the proper way to use the generated theme? 
Am I suppose to add those css classes in manually everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the classes somewhere.

You can use the [core-style element](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-style) to reuse styles or you can add the styles to the main page (`index.html`) and prefix them with `* /deep/` (like `* /deep/ .dark-primary-color) but still need to apply the classes to the elements.

Some resources about styling polymer elements

- https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html
- https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/styling.html
- https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html

Comment: What does the /deep/ do? I've never seen that in CSS before.
I can't seem to get rid of the yellow in the core-toolbar no matter what styles I put where, there's a yellow underline on the selected item as well as a yellow ripple effect when I click on the items.

Comment: Found the ripple colour: * /deep/ #ink { color: ...}, now just to get rid of that yellow underline.

Comment: The yellow colour I'm referring to is "#ffff8d", I can't find it anywhere in the dom. I did however find it in paper-tab.css. Will see if I can override it somehow.

Comment: I don't know if this is still an open question. The elements inside the `<template>` element of a Polymer element are wrapped in a shadow DOM. To pierce through shadow DOM boundaries you need to add `/deep/` (any number of boundaries) or `::shadow` (just one boundary) (see the added links for more details). It might be necessary to add additional selectors to increase the selectivity to override styles (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988837, http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c).

Comment: Thanks Günter, that makes sense! Some of the material design elements have colours defined inside their templates, at DEVOXX last year the Google engineers said that colour should not be defined inside your own templates, only layout styles, seems like they're breaking their own rule here. Don't know if I should log a bug or just work around it by overriding the CSS colour with * /deep/ #selectionBar {